# Detect when user logs back in

Tags: c#, winforms, session, .net-2.0, authentication

I have a winforms app (C# .net 2.0) that is running in sys tray. The user can log off from the system and is presented with Windows' usual login screen.

I want to detect when user logs back in.

I know there is a `SessionEnding` event to detect when user logs out. I need the reverse of that event if exists.

I need to take special action only when the app is started as a result of "log off-log back in" sequence and not when computer (OS actually) boots up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When a user logs off, all of their running applications are closed**, including your WinForms app that is minimized to the taskbar's notification area. The purpose of the `SessionEnding` event is for you to shut down your app gracefully when the user logs off or the computer is shutting down. There is no corresponding `SessionBeginning` event because your app is not automatically reopened when the user logs back in.

If you want your application to be automatically started whenever the user logs in, you need to place it in the "Startup" folder. All of the programs in that folder will be started automatically when the user logs in.

You can either configure your installer to place the application in the user's "Startup" folder (use the [`CSIDL_STARTUP` environment variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104.aspx) to find the correct location) or the common "Startup" folder shared by *all* users (use the `CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP` environment variable). Of course, if you don't have an installer, you can always place a shortcut to your application into that folder manually.

Comment: The app is already configured to be started at startup and when the user logs in, it's starting.

Comment: Sooo...I'm not sure what you're asking then. You want to detect when the user logs in? It's whenever your app starts. Put your code in one of the application's loading events. Like the `Main` method in the `Program.cs` file, or the `Load` event handler of your main form.

Comment: My app can start when OS start or it can start when the user logs back in after he logged out. I need to diferenciate between the two. In the second case the OS is not shutdown and all system windows services are still running.

Comment: How are you configuring it to start with the OS?  Do you expect the user to take over this instance when they login or to start a new instance?

Comment: Your app cannot start "when the OS start" unless it is a service, it can only start when a user logs in. There is no distinction between a user being logged in automatically (on boot) and one logging out and back in.

Comment: Having said that, I can imagine a solution: Write a service that starts on boot. When your application starts up it can query this service to find out if it is the first instance to do so. That's not bullet-proof as your app could be terminated during a user session and restarted.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue using a workaround specific to the current app.